# How do I create an '.svg.png' image?

Tags: html, svg

I keep seeing images with the file format '.svg.png'. Not sure how they work as SVG is vector based and a PNG is raster image.

So can anyone tell me;

- What are the benefits of using them?
- How do I create them. I can't see in illustrator how to export as a svg.png.

Many thanks

Comment: Isn't it just an .svg file rendered to PNG, where they've just appended the .png extension to the original full file name? So what you're asking for will just be a way to render SVGs as PNGs (which I don't know).

Comment: Hi Rup, my questions have been answered. I thought i would missing out on something;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an ordinary PNG. The .svg part of the filename just tells anyone who uses it that it was created in SVG format (so there is an SVG version floating around somewhere if they want a large version or want to make changes). Just export the file to PNG and manually type .svg.png on the end. You should only do this if you are actually saving the original as SVG so that others can edit it.

Answer (score 3):

The `.svg.png` extension tells you that it's a `png` image that was rendered from an `svg` image (and the one that did the conversion simply appended the `png` extension to the original filename to keep the name of the file that was the source of the conversion).

To do such a conversion, you can use different tools:

- A [web application](http://www.fileformat.info/convert/image/svg2raster.htm)
- A [firefox extension](http://www.treebuilder.de/default.asp?file=660000.xml)
- A [PHP class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5334-PHP-Render-a-SVG-graphic-as-a-PNG-image.html)
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (also provides a [Perl extension](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php?ImageMagick=i5c3btovm2a5jnmv0c7n6ifcb6))

And surely a lot more...

I think the main rationale to pass a `png` instead of an `svg` back to the browser is that some legacy browsers aren't able to display `svg` images directly.